# SQLite not working on Ionic 2

Tags: sqlite, typescript, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Cannot use SQLite plugin in my Angular 2/Ionic 2 project.

The way SQLite is instantiated accordint to the Ionic 2 documentation is not working.

Sublime give me an error message:

> Supplied parameters do not match nay signature of the call target.

It means that the constructor shoud receive parameters. But what parameters?

Ionic 2 SQLite plugin documentation:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/

```
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';

let db = new SQLite();
db.openDatabse({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default' // the location field is required
}).then(() => {
  db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', {}).then(() => {

  }, (err) => {
    console.error('Unable to execute sql', err);
  })
}, (err) => {
  console.error('Unable to open database', err);
});
```

It also says Property 'openDatabse' does not exist on type 'SQLite'

Comment: You've spelled Database in openDatabase wrong. Maybe that was your problem.

Comment: No. This was a problem of documentation. I corrected it and still got errors. The real solution is desbribed bellow. Probably I was usin an outdated version of Ionic 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by recreating the project from scratch and coping old app folder, configs and reinstalling npm modules and ionic native plugins.

Answer (score 1):

May be try to import SQLite object using

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
```

Note : Dont forget to install ionic-native/sqlite

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by following steps.

Add and install plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite
```

Now create a database.

```
let db = new SQLite();
            db.openDatabase({
                name: "data.db",
                location: "default"
            }).then(() => {
});
```

If you getting an error like: "openDatabse does not exist on type 'SQLite". Just delete node_module folder and reinstall node_module.

It will work.

Answer (score -1):

It's `db.openDatabase`, not Data**bs**e

But I think that now it's .create and not .openDatabase.

When you say `.then(() => {db.executeSql ...` try to add `.then((db: SQLiteObject)` and for the next then : `{}).then(() => {}, (err) => {` add data between the **( )**